# jQuery - why does the slide up and down has a jolt rather than being smooth?

Tags: jquery, css, slide, nav

I have this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(this).hoverAccordionMenu(); //build left menu accordion effects  

     /*ie6 hack for mouse over icons on 2nd level. Not part of the plugin. optional!*/
     if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) < 7) {
         //rollover arrow which doesn't work with simple css
         $('ul.menu > li > ul > li').bind("mouseenter", function (e) {
             $(this).css("background", "url(ico-arrow-level2.gif) no-repeat");
         });
         $('ul.menu > li > ul > li').bind("mouseleave", function (e) {
             $(this).not(".active").css("background", "none");
         });
     }

 });
```

I've put in to a jsfiddle to show you:

http://jsfiddle.net/haNGY/

Could anyone tell me why the slide up and down has a jolt rather than being smooth?

Thanks in advance!

(PS, Sorry, just remembered about the title, but it's nearly 4am here so my brain is on a go slow! Just went to edit it but it's been fixed, thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the jumps just do:

```
#menu ul li ul {
    width:235px;
    /* display: inline-block ;*/ /* REMOVE */
}
```

Now just something useful

```
#menu li {
    margin: 0;
    /*margin-left:0; */ /* believe me you don't need this */
}
```

```
#menu li li {
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left:9px;
    /*margin:0;*/ /* why if you already use margin 0 for LI*/
}
```

Here is also 4:49am so take a better look at the CSS... tomorrow ;)

Yeah, additionally I avoid styling the LI elements. It's not good and not always Xbrowser compatible. It's always better that you use your LI elements like dummy containers keeping minimal styling. Play with `a` elements inside to achieve the desired style.

Comment: Ha awesome thank you. Told you it was late didn't I! Something so simple! Thanks again.

EDIT: Have just seen your reply, i'll be honest those styles were modified versions of the script I downloaded.

Comment: @BN83 you're welcome! go to sleep! And looks like it was not so simple, you have 30 views and only one answer.

Comment: One other quick thing you may be able to help with, or may not who knows! In the original script i've posted, is it possible to only slide the currently open option when you mouseenter another? Currently it closes when you mouseleave.

Comment: @BN83 Look all the World is avoiding mouseenter/leave events on vertical accordions. I suggest you to follow that praxis for the good of User experience. Use clicks. http://roxon.in/scripts/simplest-vertical-accordion.html

Comment: Would it be easy enough to make an onclick event that closes the open one and open's the clicked one? If that makes sense!

Comment: @BN83 if you take a look at the link I gave you in my comment you'll see that is possible!

Comment: You just added that you sneaky sausage!! haha

Comment: Using the click example you've posted, i've done this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zrs8E/

Is it possible to add things like hover to the script to change the colour of a button when it is hovered over or when it is in it's clicked state?

Thanks!

Comment: At the moment i've got this:

   `$('.button').hover(function(){
 $(this).addClass('buttonhover');
}, function(){
 $(this).removeClass('buttonhover');
});


    $(".button").click(function () {
 
   $(this).addClass('buttonclicked');
 
    });
 
    $(".button").click(function () {
 
   $(this).removeClass('buttonclicked');
 
    });`

The hover one is working fine, but clicking it isn't holding the colour of the font, any ideas??

Comment: @BN83 You're forgetting that CSS can handle hover pretty well. Than your next error is that you're binding 2 simultaneous clicks on `.button`. that add and at the same time remove that active class. Hope you see the wrong logic. I suggest you to explore the `.not()` jQuery selector, and explore ALL the available jQuery methods.

Comment: I've sorted the hover on my links that don't have child links, but the ones that do aren't links, and I can't get :hover to work unless it's a:hover. Is there a way in CSS?

Will research the `.not()` selector. Got to be honest though, i'm really not very good in jquery, it's all new to me!